# How to use gloss accelerate to render mandelbrot

Tags: haskell, gloss, accelerate-haskell

as an exercise I'm trying to render the Mandelbrot set using Haskell. I'm using gloss to display the result. So far I got the math correct, and displaying works. At the moment I generate a [[Word8]] which represents the iterations it took for each pixel to run to infinity and convert that to a ByteString, which I use to construct a gloss Picture, which I display. It works all fine and dandy and up to a resolution of a couple 100 pixels as width and height it goes reasonably fast, but then it takes way to long. So, to change that I am now trying to use accelerate to use the GPU to render, but I just don't have any idea what to do. It starts with what library to use. Plain accelerate? gloss-accelerate? gloss-raster-accelerate? I think, I have to use the last one. In the module Graphics.Gloss.Accelerate.Raster.Array a function makePicture exists, which I think I have to use, but I can't make sense of all the parameters and I haven't found a lot of documentation.

Could somebody explain the makePicture funktion to me, or at least point me to somewhere it is a bit more explained. A working example, which I can adjust to my case would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the mandelbrot example from the [github example directory](https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate-examples/tree/master/examples/mandelbrot) from Accelerate. That one uses the accelerate and accelerate-gloss package. To give an idea of how you can program a Mandelbrot in Accelerate, there is this [tutorial](http://www.acceleratehs.org/examples/mandelbrot.html).

And more specific on the question of the `makePicture` [function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-raster-accelerate-2.1.0.0/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Accelerate-Raster-Array.html#v:makePicture).

It has 5 arguments

1. The first indicates how Accelerate should `Render` the world that was given. When using the GPU, you should use `run1` from the [`accelerate-llvm-ptx`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate-llvm-ptx-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Array-Accelerate-LLVM-PTX.html#v:run1) package.
2. Pixel width in integers.
3. Pixel height in integers.
4. Function to create the image with type `Arrays world => (Acc world -> Acc (Array DIM2 Colour))`. Thus given a function with some parameters, where the parameters should be Accelerate `Arrays`. Probably a tuple of scalars in your case, so you can indicate the range of the image you want to display. The resulting array is a matrix that needs to be of type [`Colour`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour-accelerate-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Array-Accelerate-Data-Colour-RGBA.html#t:Colour) (A tuple of 4 floats). My guess is that the dimension of the resulting array should correspond with the pixel width and pixel height you gave as arguments.
5. The unlifted `world` (i.e. without `Acc` in front of it). The parameters that are given to the function of the fourth argument.

After that, it should produce a Gloss `Picture`.